# What is the etymology of 'physician'?

Tags: etymology

I find myself confusing 'physician' and 'physicist' occasionally. While I know what they both mean, I am a little confused as to the use of 'physics' in 'physician'. How did the term 'physician' come to be used the way it is meant today? Lucky coincidence?

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/16816/1995 may assist.

Comment: relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/usage-of-ist-and-ian-when-to-use-which

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to understand the emergence of *physician* is by looking at the allied term *physic*, which *Merriam Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines and derives as follows:

> **physic** *n* [ME *physik* natural science, art of medicine, fr. AF *phisique*, *fisik*, fr. L *physica*, sing. natural science, fr. Gk *physikē*, fr. fem. of *physikos*—more at PHYSICS] (14c) **1 a :** the art or practice of healing disease **b :** the practice or profession of medicine **2 :** a medicinal agent or or preparation; *esp* : PURGATIVE **3 :** *archaic* : NATURAL SCIENCE

So a *physician* (derived from "ME *phisicien*, *fisicien*, fr. AF, fr. *phisique* medicine" according to MW) was simply someone who practiced *physic*—a natural science of healing. The only complication to this point is that MW says that *physician* emerged in the thirteenth century—one century before *physic* did.

As for the derivation of *physics*, MW has this:

> [L *physica*, pl., natural science, fr. Gk *physika*, fr. neut. pl. of *physikos* of nature, fr. *physis* growth, nature, fr. *phyein*, to bring forth—more at BE] (1715)

The word *physicist*, as Rossitten notes in another answer, came along later still (circa 1840, according to Merriam-Webster).

This chronology suggests that *physic* and *physician* were well established from their Latin root of "natural science" by the time *physics* and *physicist* showed up to share dictionary space with them. So perhaps the more searching question would be, How did a root term that meant "nature" and that had long been associated with the natural science of medicine gain a separate meaning that focused on (as MW puts it) "matter, energy, and their interactions"?

With regard to that question, I can only suppose that eighteenth-century European scientists considered that the Greek root word for nature was strong enough to accommodate a second, separate branch (to confuse the imagery a bit) of scientific inquiry.

---

**UPDATE: *Two supplemental points from commenters***

Two commenters have provided valuable additional information in response to my original answer. Because comments aren't preserved in the same way that answers are, I want to make sure that these don't get lost. First, in response to my speculation about how European scientists came to adapt the Latin *physica* and the Greek *physikos*, Frank points out that the OED reports a remarkable 1840 discussion of *physician* versus *physicist*:

> *1840 Whewell Philos. Induct. Sci. Pref. 71 We might perhaps still use physician as the equivalent of the French physicien‥but probably it would be better to coin a new word. Thus we may say that‥the Physicist proceeds upon the ideas of force, matter, and the properties of matter.*

But prior to that *physicist* had been used to mean “[One versed in medical science](https://books.google.com/books?id=ERJYAAAAYAAJ&q=%22one+versed+in+medical+science%22&dq=%22one+versed+in+medical+science%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCGoVChMI1MXntJzDxwIVgy6ICh0Zrw8y)”:

> *1716 M. Davies Athen. Brit. III. Diss. Physick 12 Anatomists, Naturalists, Physicists, Medicinist*

Second, regarding the same issue of the shared Greek root of *physic* and *physics*, Janus Bahs Jacquet offers these thoughts:

> [I]t is noteworthy that the Greek root is (in Greek) transparently connected with the base noun *φύσις* and its underlying verb *φύειν*, both of which refer to making something grow, creating something, bringing something into being. The underlying root is PIE *bheuH-, which simply means ‘be’, so the ultimate sense of *physic(al)* is just ‘relating to that which is’. Not a stretch to go from there to ‘nature, the natural world’, but also not a stretch to go to ‘matter, essence, energy’.

My thanks to both of these commenters for their insights.

Comment: OED has explicit mention of the coinage of _physicist_ (for matters non-medical). _1840 Whewell Philos. Induct. Sci. Pref. 71 We might perhaps still use physician as the equivalent of the French physicien‥but probably it would be better to coin a new word. Thus we may say that‥the Physicist proceeds upon the ideas of force, matter, and the properties of matter._ But prior to that it has been used to mean _One versed in medical science_ _1716 M. Davies Athen. Brit. III. Diss. Physick 12 Anatomists, Naturalists, Physicists, Medicinist_

Comment: As to your last paragraphs, it is noteworthy that the Greek root is (in Greek) transparently connected with the base noun _φύσις_ and its underlying verb _φύειν_, both of which refer to making something grow, creating something, bringing something into being. The underlying root is PIE _*bheuH-_, which simply means ‘be’, so the ultimate sense of _physic(al)_ is just ‘relating to that which _is_’. Not a stretch to go from there to ‘nature, the natural world’, but also not a stretch to go to ‘matter, essence, energy’.

Answer (score 5):

**physicist** (n.) 
    1836, from physics + -ist. Coined by the Rev. William Whewell (1794-1866), English polymath, to denote a "cultivator of physics" as opposed to a physician.

As we cannot use physician for a cultivator of physics, I have called him a physicist. We need very much a name to describe a cultivator of science in general. I should incline to call him a Scientist. Thus we might say, that as an Artist is a Musician, Painter, or Poet, a Scientist is a Mathematician, Physicist, or Naturalist. [William Whewell, "The Philosophy of the Inductive Sciences," London, 1840]

[Etymonline source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=physicist&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: While the etymology of **physicist** is certainly related to the question, I think an answer should first and foremost answer the OP's actual question - what the etymology of **physician** is.

Answer (score 5):

*physica* is from the Latin for natural science. As physician (internal medicine doctor) it comes through the Old French *fisiciien*. Originally a medic would have to study natural science, plants and the nature of the body (as well as Astrology), while a lowly surgeon merely had to have a sharp knife and a strong stomach.

Physicist is from the same root with a different ending to avoid confusion, as user 'Rossitten' describes in his answer on this same page.

Answer (score 0):

Physician is a very old word, coming from **both Greek and Latin** roots for physic, meaning "natural science and medicine."