# Roboticist v.s. Robotician

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity

I am wondering about the right word to explain the people, are who involved in the robotics realm.

I've seen both Roboticist and Robotician within the technical literature. But I have no idea about their potential difference and the probable underlying criterion for right utilization of each one.

Is anybody able to clear the case?

Comment: I think *robotician* (not in many dictionaries, certainly not in the full OED) is just a "geek" coinage based on *technician* that currently has almost no traction (and isn't likely to take off, imho).

Comment: Are you sure "robotician" is even a word? I can't find any definition of it...

Comment: There will soon be enough specialties to take up all the words that can be made: _robotologist, roboticist, robotician, robotomologist, robotist, robotique, Robotiker,_ you name it.

Comment: I think the differences are in the respective suffixes (if there is a recognized difference) and the -ist/-ian/-ite debate has been covered already.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Are all of these term legal in a linguistic manner?!

Comment: @Misneac: Would you please address the aforementioned coverage of that debate?

Comment: @Matinking: When they're needed and provided, they will be. Nobody can predict that kind of future. Imagine an algorithm that predicted the names of rock bands over the last 40 years; about equivalent in difficulty. And there is no "legal" involved; languages are self-enforcing, like gravity.

Comment: @Matinking I read it the other day on here and if IIRC it dealt with christian, buddhist and shiite in the OP. I should also add that I believe the suffix -ist typically means someone who does the thing referred to, but I'd be hard pressed to prove it without spending a long time looking for my source.

Comment: From fuzzily remembered old knowledge I think the -ist/-ian difference had something to do originally with empirical vs theoretical knowledge. Perhaps that's why physicists advanced much more rapidly than physicians.

Comment: @Misneac: This definition sounds reasonable and I ought to investigate o it, considerably. Thanks

Comment: The entertainment show "Robot Wars" in the UK, uses roboteers. This is not a good source or answer, but thought it would add to the spice of the question.

Comment: @DanSheppard: Thanks... Now the crux of the problem even has become more diversified... :)

Comment: "Roboticist" was apparently coined by [Isaac Asimov in 1946](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/1134).

Comment: @bof: Will such fact decrease the credibility of "Roboticist" in comparison with "Robotician"???

Comment: Relevant: [What is the etymology of 'physician'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222567/what-is-the-etymology-of-physician), [Usage of -ist and -ian, when to use which?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119717)