# How did 'nature' semantically narrow to mean 'medical science'?

Tags: etymology

> [physic (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=physic&allowed_in_frame=0)
> [1.]    c. 1300, *fysike*, "art of healing, **medical science**," also "natural science" (c. 1300),
> [2.] from Old French *fisike* **"natural science, art of healing"** (12c.)
> [3.] and directly from Latin *physica* (fem. singular of *physicus*) "study of nature,"
>
> [4.] from Greek *physike* (*episteme*) **"(knowledge) of nature,"**
> from fem. of *physikos* "pertaining to nature," from *physis* "nature,"
> from *phyein* "to bring forth, produce, make to grow" (related to phyton "growth, plant," phyle "tribe, race," phyma "a growth, tumor")
> from PIE root **bheue-* "to be exist, grow" (see [be](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=be&allowed_in_frame=0)).    […]

How can [4.] possibly be connected to [1.] and [2.]?  I'm uneducated in the history of medicine.  To wit, how did the bolded in [4.]
narrow semantically to mean the bolded in 1 and 2?

Comment: Is not "knowledge of nature" directly relatable to "natural science" in those definitions?

Comment: The etymology of the underlying Greek term *physis,* with its emphasis on *growth,* points to an organic rather than mechanistic conception of “nature,” which gives the expression *physikē epistēmē,* “natural science,” a bent more towards biology than towards what we call “physics.” And medicine is among the obvious applications of biological science.

Comment: Please indicate the source dictionary of your quotation.  What makes you think definition 4 narrowed to 1? Without knowing how the dictionary works I would assume that the four represent independent origins and usages, with direct borrowing from Latin or Greek being *later* than the others, not earlier introductions into English.

Comment: @David The root of ‘natura’ is ‘nascor’, with the participle ‘natus’ (as in ‘Christus natus est’).  But the poet Lucretius named his verse version of the Alexandrian Greek atomist, Epicurus is titled “De Rerum Natura”.  And this did not mean ‘nature’ as in Sir David Attenborough, but rather as in Brian Cox.  Everything there is is composed of atoms (including the human soul).  Death is the dissipation of the atoms that make us up and so our final end.  So, like Greek ‘physis’, ‘natura’ also made a transition from being concerned with ‘nature’ to coming into existence in a more general sense.

Comment: @Tuffy, the OP's question is about the relationship between nature/physics on one side, and **medical** science or the art of **healing** on the other side. In case the dictionary entry quoted by the OP does not seem visibly related to ordinary present-day English, the core of the question can be brought out more clearly by asking how it came about that the word *physician* stands for a practitioner of medicine, rather than being a general term for somebody working in the field of natural science.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the etymology of 'physician'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222567/what-is-the-etymology-of-physician), although it is possible that the OP will not regard the present question to have been fully answered there.

Comment: @jsw29 I did read that question, but as you surmised, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this question, the understanding of which depends on a prior awareness of the history of ‘science’, first in ancient Greece and then (thanks to the Arab civilisation) its resumption in the Late Middle Ages through to the Enlightenment and onwards.

The second point of which to be aware is that many Greeks by the 5th century had begun to separate in their minds things caused by human action from things outside human agency.  The notorious example of this is that many of the so-called ‘sophists’, such as Antiphon, had begun to distinguish between ‘nomos’ (meaning *law/convention* and by these thinkers to things and causes whose existence is only a matter human cultural intervention) and ‘physis’ (*nature*, in the sense of the truly real).  Notoriously, this led some to question the validity of law and morality themselves, as ideas with no ‘real’ existence and therefore no claim on our obedience.  Plato, in his dialogue *Gorgias*, makes his character Callicles insist that justice is no more than a device of the weak to deny the strong their ‘natural’ right to have it all their own way.   [It is not difficult to think of people who think this way today.].  Much of Plato’s ethical project was to try to show that virtues like *justice*, *wisdom* and *self-control* did exist as **real** things in ‘physis’ not merely as ‘nomos’.

At the same time, came the development of mathematics, astronomy and cosmology/cosmogony (no doubt from Babylonian, Egyptian and, via these, ultimately Indian beginnings).  First, in the school of Miletus (C6 BCE) Thales proposed that everything in ‘nature’ was actually water in some form, and that the differences between different substances and their observed changes (such as seed to plant, say, or grass to milk via cow) must, if not magic, be because it is all in some way originally the same, in changing states.  They took, in a way, magic out of the picture.  This culminated in the atomism of Leucippus and Democritus, where everything is made of combinations of tiny invisible particles, joined up together somehow.  Of course the average Greek in the street thought this at best crazy and at worst impiety against the gods.

But here we can see how a word like ‘physis’ can become detached from its roots in living nature and come to represent all there *really* is.  So when he wrote the *Physics*, Aristotle was writing about what we now call *physics*.  And physicists will tell you that chemistry and biology boil down to physics!

With the rise of Christianity, this kind of science came to be seen as dangerous and heretical.  The early christian fathers did their best to destroy all traces of it, and might have succeeded but for Arab scholars, who translates Aristotle and others into Arabic.

A similar process was repeated between the Late Middle Ages and the Enlightenment.  Most science concerned ‘physic’ and so the word went back to that use.  Alchemy was deeply suspect, until chemistry gradually emerged.  What really enabled *physics* to return to its Aristotelian use was probably the arrival of direct astronomical observation through the telescope.  However, it may also be significant that in the late 16th/early 17th century, a French physician named Jean Chrysostom Magnen (Iohannus Chrysostomus Magnenus 1590-1679), working in the University of Dôle in the Free County of Burgundy, published his work *Democritus Revivescens Vel De Atomis* - *Democritus Reborn or On Atoms*.  He joined the medical faculty of the University of Pavia  in Italyand published his work in 1646.  As far as I can tell, he did not use the term *physics*, and still used the Latin term *elementa*.  The doors did not all open at once or the language change.  But it was a start.

Comment: I should have pointed out that the word ‘natura’ was never confined to nature alla David Attenborough.  The Roman poet Lucretius set out the scientific atomism, which the Alexandrian Greek, Epicurus derived from Democritus, in his didactic poem ‘de rerum natura’.  Here, the word ‘natura’ is clearly used in the sense in which Aristotle used ‘physics’ a century or so before.

Comment: +1. Thanks. "It is not difficult to think of people who think this way today." Whom are you referring to? I can't think of these people?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal People who thin which way?  Sorry if I’m being dense.

Comment: I was referring to your 2nd last sentence in para. 2: `Plato, in his dialogue Gorgias, makes his character Callicles insist that justice is no more than a device of the weak to deny the strong their ‘natural’ right to have it all their own way. [It is not difficult to think of people who think this way today.].'

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal  Sorry, dense of me.  Would it be cowardly to answer:  "No names, no pack drill."?