# Is it correct to use the suffix -ian when referring to names?

Tags: grammar, suffixes

Oftentimes when reading academic texts I will come across the suffix "-ian" as a way to denote ownership.  While I find it fitting syntactically (it "feels" right), I don't remember ever learning it specifically in school, etc.  For example:

> **Wilsonian** (Wilson's) moral diplomacy is widely regarded as a failure.
>
> **Carverian** (Carver's) Minimalism marked a rebirth of the realist movement.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is this syntax correct?
2. If so, What mood does it give off?  Does it offer an academic tone, etc.?
3. Is it possible to use this with any name, or just a few popular ones?  Can I say "Flafla2-ian"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In older works, there is often a tradition of Latinizing the stem of the name to match the ending; thus the adjective that goes with "Shaw" is "Shavian", "Liverpool" is "Liverpudlian," "Newcastle" is "Novocastrian" (although the latter two correspond to places rather than people).

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of a few more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English

Comment: Interesting.  So it appears that the -ian suffix is not universal (as, for example, 's as in Flafla2's).  The latin root of the phrase may be the root of its academic feel.

Comment: -ian does not work  well with the name of Kafka (ending in a vowel). The adjective is Kafkaesque. And I would describe -ian as suffix for adjective derivation from family names, not as suffix of ownership.

Comment: I forgot to mention Kafkaesque means in the style of Kafka.

Comment: Since flafla2 ends in the sound /u/, I think the adjective would be flafla2-vian. As in, Nehruvian, Peruvian.

Comment: It does seem to depend on what sounds best: Dickensian v. Dylanesque.

Comment: This question appears to be encompassed by the existing question [Usage of -ist and -ian, when to use which?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/usage-of-ist-and-ian-when-to-use-which/)

Comment: Since OP was asking for tone, I would suggest that the eponyms might presuppose knowledge of the person and what he is famous for. So "Wilsonian" is fine because we all know Woodrow (except perhaps for Brits of a certain vintage who think of Harold), but "Carverian" may be pushing it. We talking Raymond Carver or someone else?

Comment: @DavidPugh Yes, in this case I was referring to Raymond Carver.  I would probably use that in, for example, an essay.  In that context I feel it would be appropriate.

Comment: @sumelic: Your comment makes me wonder whether the adjective that goes with "Ellen Glasgow" might be "Glaswegian."

Comment: -esque is **not** the same as -ian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct and [rather neutral](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ian), as long as the set of concepts belonging to said person really is codified: saying "that's a Flafla2ian question" is at best ironic as no such style of asking is known.

Other suffixes have a different meanings, for instance [-esque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-esque) is used for any resemblance, which may be a caricature.

Comment: And it should be noted that the suffix simply doesn't "sound right", or is perhaps unpronounceable, when attached to some names.